# Making d3 truly responsive, just like highcharts

Tags: svg, d3.js, highcharts

Most of the solutions I've found to make d3gprahs to be responsive is all about the svg's viewbox and updating it on window resize.

The problem with that is that it just simply resizes the svg. If you make the window smaller the font will get smaller, the graph will get tiny and so forth. If you start off with a small window and make it bigger it will only "zoom" in the svg.

Highcharts handles this pretty nice. But highcharts updates every object to fit the new size. If the page is heavy on the graphs, it will lead to some heavy burden on the browser. But still, it's very nice and userfriendly.

Is there a similar way to do this for d3? or do I have to recount everything on window resize?

Comment: D3 doesn't do this automatically, you have to redraw everything yourself.

Comment: So, Highcharts lib is bad, because updates every object (in terms of performance). d3 is bad because doesn't update every object (in terms of user-experience) ?

Comment: Pawel, that pretty much sums it up.
Lars ye... sadly. Was hoping for someone to come up with a miracle fix

Comment: www.brendansudol.com/posts/responsive-d3/